# Strange behavior using try catch for Unhandled Exception

Tags: php

I have the following code in my project for routing if i go to example.com/test and test doesn't exist
it will produce the custom 404 error in my framework as it should

```
/* Routing */
$router = new application\libraries\router();
$router->add('', ['controller' => 'main', 'action' => 'index']);
$router->add('login', ['controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'new']);
$router->add('logout', ['controller' => 'Login', 'action' => 'destroy']);
$router->add('{controller}/{action}');

$router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

The problem is in my phpstorm console of current file it gives a weak warning
line **Unhandled \Exception line 40**

The following is line 40

```
$router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

The suggested fix according to phpstorm is to surround with **try-catch**
so I did the following

```
try {
    $router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

The warning goes away but then if I try a url that don't exist it wont show the custom error messages i created. it only works without the **try-catch**

Comment: Display the error message you want in the `catch` block.

Comment: What's the actual exception being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which router you are using, but you have to actually handle the exception. So, what you did is probably correct, you just need to add a step.

If a non-existing route is presented and your router throws the exception, you should write the code to handle it in the catch block. Like so:

```php
try {
    $router->dispatch($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

This is a very simplified example, your $router object might have the option to just send a 404 maybe?

Also, check what kind of Exception your router throws. For example, you might want to handle a RouteNotFoundException differently than a RouteIsPrivateException. You can use multiple catch statements to check for multiple types of exceptions.

Have a look here for more info on exceptions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php